How to get the ETH balance after calling getSigners()
I have a single metamask address with a BNB balance on the BNB Chain Mainnet and an ETH balance on Arbitrum One.  Calling my typescript script below:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_prod.ts --network arbitrum

hardhat.config.ts has this network key in it:
 const arbitrum_provider_url = process.env.ARBITRUM_PROVIDER_URL!;

    arbitrum: {
  url: arbitrum_provider_url,
  chainId: 42161,
  accounts: [private_key],
},

In the deploy_prod.ts script, I use the ethers.getSigners() method and attempt to get the ETH balance, and it returns the ETH balance when the --network arbitrum network is passed in, but if I have a second token in the wallet, WETH as an example, on the arbitrum network in the same wallet account, how do I access that?
  const [signer1] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const address1 = (await signer1.getAddress()).toString();
  const balance1 = (await signer1.getBalance()).toString();
  console.log(`✓ Address ${address1} with ${balance1}`);


You're getting the BNB balance even when using --network arbitrum flag while executing the script ?

Another way of asking this question--if I have multiple tokens in a single account on a single network,  how do I specify a particular token and get that individual token's balance?

Any other token that you're having except from the native network token (i.e., BNB in case of Binance, ETH in case of Arbitrum, etc) is an ERC20 token. So, you've to get the balance using the address of that particular token, and calling its balanceOf function. If you could share more context regarding the tokens whose balances you're retrieving, then I would be able to share a code snippet for the same.

Update:   So you were correct to begin with--my mistake--when I designated --network arbitrum on the script run in the beginning, I was actually looking at the ETH balance, not the BNB balance when I did getSigners--totally my mistake.   My apologies for the confusion.   I've edited my question.   If I have two tokens in the same wallet account on arbitrum--let's say ether and weth--as an example, how do I get the weth balance?   Is that the balanceOf function that you stated?   Or is there another element in the returned array for ethers.getSigners()?   Thanks so much for your help!

I’ve added the example of calling the balanceOf() function of the WETH token contract in my answer. Please check.

To get the balance of WETH token on the Arbitrum network, you can call the balanceOf() function of the corresponding token contract:

const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(arbitrum_provider_url);
const wethAddress = "0x82af49447d8a07e3bd95bd0d56f35241523fbab1";
const balanceOf_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(wethAddress, balanceOf_ABI, provider);

tokenContract.balanceOf(address1).then((wethBalance) => {
    console.log("WETH balance (in Wei): ", parseInt(wethBalance.toString()));
    console.log("WETH balance (in Ether): ", parseFloat(ethers.formatUnits(wethBalance)));
});

